# I lost my crosshair and my hotbar in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I lost my crosshair and hotbar in Minecraft. When I press <kbd>F1</kbd> they come back, but then all the things like coords come out and I don't know how to get it to go away.

Comment: I would personally recommend facerolling across your F-keys. I actually recognize the issue and I do remember having it and solving it myself but I don't actually remember how so I'll refrain from giving an answer. I am certain it's a button to hide the interface for screenshots and whatnot.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>? Pressing that toggles the coordinates display. You can also try logging out then logging back in.